# upon data retrieval, form populates and then clears

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a weird problem.  I have a form that populates with a button click event.  This all works fine, except that once the form populates, it clears itself.  Even Firebug gets cleared.  I have stripped everything down to its most basic level, and cannot figure out what the issue is.
HTML:

```
<?php

require_once('../hyperlink.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Shipment Assignment</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="book.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/tabletheme/style.css" type="text/css" id="" media="print, projection, screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../barcode/jquery-barcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="book.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">

<?php display_user_hyperlinks(); ?>

<?php include ('../version.php'); ?>  | Tip: Shipping Info</p>

</div>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Shipping Assignments</legend>
Enter the PO that you would like to review: <input id="po"/><input type="submit" id="getPo" value="Retrieve"/>
</fieldset></form>
<form id="result">
<div id="hide">
    <div id="cl" class="width border">
        CL<input id="cl"/>
    </div>
    <div id="recv" class="width border">
        REC<input id="rec"/>
    </div>
    <div id="pricePd" class="width border">
        <input id="price" placeholder="Price Paid"/>
    </div>
    <div id="box" class="border">
        <input id="title" style="width: 445px;" placeholder="Title"/><br>
        <input id="isbn10" style="width: 445px;" placeholder="ISBN10"/><br>
        <input id="isbn13" style="width: 445px;" placeholder="ISBN13"/><br>
    </div>
</div></form>
    <div id="remain"class="border">
    Qty Rem: <input type="text"  id="qtyRem"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

book.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#getPo").click(function() {

    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "poInfo.php",
        async:false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: ({po: $('#po').val()}),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            $("#isbn13").val(data.isbn);
            $("#isbn10").val(data.isbn10);
            $("#title").val(data.title);

       }
   }); //END OF AJAX
 }); // END OF GETPO FUNCTION

});
```

poInfo.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',"1");
require_once ('../db.php');
$conn = db_connect();
$i=0;
$po = 'JJD090969';

$result = $conn->query("select * from ship_assign where po = '$po'");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$isbn10 = $row['isbn10'];
$isbn = $row['isbn13'];
$azLow = $row['azLow'];
$buyback101 = $row['Buyback101'];
$textRecycle = $row['textBookRecycle'];
$textRush = $row['textBookRush'];
$bookStores = $row['bookStores'];
$textBooks = $row['textBooks'];
$bookJingle = $row['bookJingle'];
$cash4Books = $row['cash4Books'];
$bookbyte = $row['bookbyte'];
$sellBack = $row['sellBack'];
$cheggBs = $row['chegg'];
$valore = $row['valore'];
$powell = $row['powell'];
$amzBuyBack = $row['amazonBuyBack'];
$collegeBooksDir = $row['collegeBooksDirect'];

$result2 = $conn->query("select title from book where isbn13 = '$isbn'");
$row1 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
$title = $row1['title'];
} //END OF WHILE STATEMENT
$guides= array('isbn10'=>$isbn10,'isbn'=>$isbn,'title'=>$title);

$conn->close();
echo json_encode($guides);
?>
```

Everything works as it should, except that the form clears once populated.  I am hard coding in the po that I want to use instead of having to type it in every time, but the result is the same either way.  Any ideas on how to fix this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#getPo").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "poInfo.php",
       // async:false, deprecated
        dataType: "json",
        data: ({po: $('#po').val()}),
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            $("#isbn13").val(data.isbn);
            $("#isbn10").val(data.isbn10);
            $("#title").val(data.title);

       }
   }); //END OF AJAX
 }); // END OF GETPO FUNCTION

});
```

Comment: everything still clears and i get an error that reads event.preventDefault() event is not defined

Comment: try replacing .click(function() with .click(function(event). Hope it works,

Comment: That seems to work, can you explain what it is doing please?  Thanks

Comment: event.preventdefault(); method stops the default action of an element from happening and **async** is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.